# clicking multiple times on a link or page number in grid view thows an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have got a button field in my grid view. When I click multiple times on the grid (3 times), I am getting an error which is shown below. The same issue is arised when I click multiple times on a page number(which is not the active page)  of the grid.

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

Please help me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have added databinding code in page load without enclosing `IsPostBack` block.

```
void page_load()
{
  if(!IsPostBack) 
   {
    //put databinding code here
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Please read these threads/posts:

1. [Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228969/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-event-validation-is-enabled-using-pages)
2. MSDN blog - [Validation of viewstate MAC failed error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx)
3. [Validation of viewstate MAC failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331720/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed)
4. [Validation of viewstate MAC failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226481/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error)

Comment: The databinding is enclosed in (!IsPostback) event. I tried with giving EnableEventValidation="false" for the page. Then another error message is raised which is ------------------------- "Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster."

Comment: @user.net I'm too! a victim of this. There are different work-around and suggestions. I'm pasting other links on this subject. Hope this will help you out.